# MIPS programming basic for-loop

Tags: java, assembly, mips, mips32

I am currently writing a mips program which does factorial. I have written the factorial example in java, and have also have the MIPS program below the java code. I have the majority of the MIPS written out, but am confused why it is not processing correctly. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Java code for the iteratve factorial algorithm:
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FactorMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to be factored: ");
        input = in.nextInt();
        {
            int x, factorial = 1;
            for (x = input; x > 1; x--)
                factorial *= x;
            System.out.println("Factorial #" + input + " is " + factorial);
        }
    }
}
```

MIPS CODE:

```
    .data
p1: .asciiz "Enter an integer to be factored: "
ans1:   .asciiz "Factorial # "
ans2:   .asciiz " is "
ans3:   .asciiz "\n\n"

    .text
    .globl main

main:   li $v0, 4
    la $a0, p1
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0   #this is input

    li $t1, 1       #initilize factorial
    move $t2, $t0       #initilize x


loop:
    blt $t2, 1, done
    sub $t2, $t2, 1
    mul $t3, $t1, $t0
    j loop



done:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ans1
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t3
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what the Java code does (I changed `X *= Y` to `X = X * Y` for clarity):

```
    for (x = input; x > 1; x--)
        factorial = factorial * x;
```

Now let's look at your assembly code:

```
move $t2, $t0       #initilize x
loop:
    blt $t2, 1, done
    sub $t2, $t2, 1
    mul $t3, $t1, $t0
    j loop
```

and what that would correspond to in Java:

```
for (x = input; x >= 1; ) {
    x--;
    temp = factorial * input;
}
```

Notice the differences? You're:

1. Decrementing `x` before the multiplication, instead of after like in the original Java code.
2. Multiplying by `input` (`$t0`) instead of by `x` (`$t2`).
3. Storing the result of the multiplication in a different register instead of writing it back to `factorial` (`$t1`). So you'll always get the product of `1 * input`, which of course equals `input`.

Comment: Definitely puts going back and forth in languages in perspective.